# Force iTunes update overnight using cron

Tags: itunes, snow-leopard, podcasts, upgrade

I was wondering if anyone knew a command line 'command' I could use in a cron to force the iTunes podcast updater to run overnight. I'm running 10.6

Comment: for anyone with errors using the solution see this article to fix them: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/516/cpsid_51615.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following AppleScript to ask iTunes to update all your podcast feeds:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    updateAllPodcasts
end tell
```

This AppleScript can be performed from the command line through [osascript](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to updateAllPodcasts'
```

You can use a range of tools to schedule your AppleScript to run each night. One option is to run the AppleScript as part of an iCal event: [How to Use iCal to Run an AppleScript](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011/01/12/how-to-use-ical-to-run-an-applescript/)

Alternatively, you can create a [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) [job ticket](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) and place it in your `~/Library/LaunchAgents` folder.

Comment: this is what I found online and have been getting an error which deals with 64 bit arch. I found a solution though: arch -i386 osascript  -e 'tell application "iTunes" to updateAllPodcasts' Thanks for the help! Cron works just fine for me =)

Comment: Is it possible to run this in "faceless mode", i.e. without having to open iTunes and instead perform the task in the background?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple scripts wrapped in an automator that does all of the updating for me.

The first script makes sure that podcasts that haven't been listened to in a while aren't disabled. The second script then updates the podcasts.

```
(*
"Update Expired Podcasts" for iTunes
written by Doug Adams
dougadams@mac.com

v1.0 aug 13, 2008
-- compatible with iTunes 7.7.1

v1.0 feb 15, 2007
-- initial release

Get more free AppleScripts and info on writing your own
at Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes
http://www.dougscripts.com/itunes/

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License for more details.

Get a copy of the GNU General Public License by writing to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA.

or visit http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html

*)


tell application "iTunes"
    set podcast_playlist to some playlist whose special kind is Podcasts

    -- filter multiple names
    set each_podcast to {}
    set each_podcast to my get_discrete_list_of(get album of every track of podcast_playlist)

    -- update the podcasts
    if each_podcast is not {} then
        repeat with this_podcast in each_podcast
            set the_podcast to (some track of podcast_playlist whose album contains this_podcast)
            if (get class of the_podcast) is list then set the_podcast to item 1 of the_podcast
            updatePodcast the_podcast
        end repeat
    end if

end tell


to get_discrete_list_of(list1)
    script a
        property list1ref : list1
    end script

    set list2 to {}
    script b
        property list2ref : list2
    end script

    repeat with i from 1 to length of list1
        set this_item to item i of a's list1ref
        considering case
            if this_item is not "" and this_item is not in b's list2ref then set end of list2 to this_item
        end considering
    end repeat

    return b's list2ref

end get_discrete_list_of
```

Update podcasts:

```
tell application "iTunes" to updateAllPodcasts
```

No, I wasn't the originator of the scripts, but I forgot the original source URL.

Comment: thanks for the help but I figured out a solution =)